# How do I keep Azolla (duckweed) alive in a sealed container?

Tags: plant-care

I would like to  keep Azolla (duckweed) alive for a week in a sealed container. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Good question; if could include a close illustration of the plants, and the size of the containers, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: i kept a set of lemma duckweed alive for a week in a room in open paper cups. used a variety of nutrient solutions to test different nutrient deficiencies. not a sterile envuronment. are planning like this?

Comment: I think a week is no problem , but for a longer time they need access to CO 2 from air. Direct sun light would be too hot for those containers.